Is it possible to put the incoming call activity in background ignoring the call?
I use Google Dialer and sometimes I get calls from unknown numbers, usually known for spam or scam. For safety reasons, afterwards I check these numbers in various databases and I put them to special contacts named "spammers", "scammers" (not a contact per a number, a contact may have a large number of such phone numbers), etc that have red contact images so that I'm aware of them if they recall and I ignore. Yes, it might sound weird if I can use the blacklist feature, but this small database is synced with Google Contacts and this is fine for me.
I'm not a fan of getting into "conversations" with them and I usually ignore calls from an unknown number that is not in my database. But what annoys me the most is that I seem to be unable to get out the call activity and open another application until the call is cut off: once I swipe from the bottom, the dialer picks up the phone and this is not what I want. I do not want to hang up the phone quickly because the peer might then be aware of that I noticed the call and I aborted it (by the way, if the number is in the blacklist, does Google Dialer hangs up the phone immediately?).
I feel very stupid now not seeing probably a very easy approach/solution, but I'm wondering: is there a way of putting the incoming call activity in background letting it ring until the call is considered unanswered (~40 seconds?) so that the caller wouldn't be aware the I hang up the phone myself? Suggesting a "correct swipe", an option, or a hack with a Magisk module, LSPosed, XPrivacyLua or whatever advanced is very appreciated.
I'm using:

Google Pixel 6 Pro
Android 14
root, Magisk
com.google.android.dialer 139.0.****


Edit 1
What came to my mind recently: if I'm not wrong, Google Dialer only opens full-screen when the display is off or the phone is locked, otherwise the incoming call is indicated as a small popup in top of the screen. This is the crucial thing here. The Google Dialer should use, I believe, Android API only (no native code, whatsoever). If so then, in principle, the methods that are responsible for providing the display/lock info can be replaced in a LSPosed Java module I have little experience in. This would look very and very similar to how the Call Recording module for LSPosed works, however at first glance the module seems to use JNI for whatever reason, and the magic is here. Sounds easy in theory, but yet unknown in practice.
Intercepting KeyguardManager methods is not an option I thought it might be. Unfortunately, I failed with that.

Okay, as I understand from your request is you are trying to find a method to just ignore incoming calls and put it in background instead of declining them, if that what you were asking, you can use a modded dialer if your phone was rooted like MotoDialer or something to be able to run your incoming calls in the background without interrupting your activity on the phone or forcing you to pick up the call.

Thanks for the suggestion. The module you've suggested looks promising, but I would really like to stick to Google Dialer, since the only thing that annoyis me the most is incoming call full screen activity. I have still (possibly wrong) feeling it can be patched with a Magisk or LSPosed module.

I also updated the question. I hope it clarifies what I really would like to have not switching to another app. Still don't know if it's easy to implement though.

You can try a workaround to fix your issue whenever you have an unwanted call by swiping down from the status bar to access the quick settings tiles.
Tap on the phone settings button, or long-press any of the quick settings tiles to open your phone's settings. This will force Google Dialer to switch to the notifications drop-down window. Swipe up to ignore the call in the background.

Thank you for suggested another option. To be honest, I didn't check it. It seems to be a solution, but I guess it's really overcomplicated.
